# Deleting symbolic links using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, symlink

So I wanted to create a shell script which goes through a directory and deletes any unused symbolic links/links to files which no longer exist. I done a bit of research and found ways to do it in command line but couldn't find a way to create a shell script which does this.

I wanted to be able to do **./script.sh dir_name** and it deletes the symbolic links in that directory. If someone could help me create this or let me know how it might be possible it would help a lot <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick bash script I wrote to accomplish what you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$1"

if [[ -z "$dir" ]]; then
    echo "Error, missing argument for directory to remove symlinks from"
    exit 1
fi

find "$dir" -xtype l -delete
```